# How to set blank line before every new prompt for bash on cmder?

Tags: linux, windows, command-line, bash, cmder

I'm using `cmder` as my command prompt in `windows` and also installed the `ubuntu` from `Microsoft app store` using `subsystem layer for linux`.

How to set a blank line before every new prompt for `bash` on `cmder` (I want to make case number 2  to be like number 1 which takes the commands on the next line )as you can see in the picture?

[image: How can I ensure a blank line before every new prompt?]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following example will work on Linux only,
so you will have to login into Linux (directly or remote) to benefit from it.

You can use `\n` (newline, or next line) to add a blank line to `$PS1`,
but for this to work your `~/.bashrc` doesn't need to have any fancy stuff
that will change your prompt.

```
export PS1="\n${PS1}"
```

To automate this you need to add this to your `~/.bashrc` at the bottom of that file.

When your `$PS1` is edited already then you need to post this too,
because we can't assume what else will work and what not.